# Apache Commons Math: how to perform sum along rows/columns?

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

I'm pretty new to Apache Common Math, so please pardon the trivial questions.

Based on the [API doc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html), I'm unable to figure out how to perform column-wise or row-wise sum.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.MatrixUtils;

double[][] values = {{1.0, 2.0}, {3.0, 4.0}, {5.0, 6.0}};
RealMatrix mtx = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(values);
```

The above code generate a matrix like the following:

```
[[1, 2],
 [3, 4],
 [5, 6]]
```

What's the right syntax to perform column-wise sum? Which would give me:

```
[9, 12]
```

And how do I perform row-wise sum? Which would give me:

```
[3,
 7,
 11
]
```

For comparison, below is the syntax in Scala's Breeze library:

```
import breeze.linalg._
val mtx = DenseMatrix((1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0))

// sum along the column direction
sum(mtx(::, *))
// Transpose(DenseVector(9.0, 12.0))


// sum along the row direction
sum(mtx(*, ::))
// DenseVector(3.0, 7.0, 11.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is no simple method to achieve that, how about generating a **ones matrix** to do the **sum**?, like:

```
//get the row sums
mtx.multiply(MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(new double[][]{{1}, {1}}))
> Array2DRowRealMatrix{{3.0},{7.0},{11.0}}
//get the column sums
MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(new double[][]{{1, 1, 1}}).multiply(mtx)
> Array2DRowRealMatrix{{9.0,12.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathod to calculate **sum of absolute squares of values in matrix** in *Java* using *Apache commons Math* Library : **getFrobeniusNorm()**

```
  import org.apache.commons.math4.legacy.linear.*;
  RealMatrix realMatrix;  //initialize with your values
  RealMatrix eigenVector; //initialize with your values
  RealMatrix dotProduct = realMatrix.multiply(eigenVector);
  double normalizedValue = dotProduct.getFrobeniusNorm();
```

Formula :  Frobenius norm of matrix = sqrt( Sum(|a_(ij)|^2) ) where i=0 to m and j=0 to n